# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php4l8IAc' to upload dir

Tags: php

I'm getting error when I move the uploaded file. I checked upload path,it seems correct and also I checked directory permission too (755 - 777 both of them).

But it still I'm getting this error, what is my mistake ?

file uploader class

```
public function __construct($file,$mimes = ["jpg","png","jpeg"],$size = null)
    {
     $this->file = $file;
     $this->mimes = $mimes;
     $this->sSize = $size;
     $this->butcher();
    }
private function butcher(){

    $this->realName = pathinfo($this->file->name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $this->size = $this->file->size;
    $this->error = $this->file->error;
    $this->tmpName = $this->file->tmp_name;

    $this->checkErrors();
} // and some control functions...

private function createUniqueName()
{
    $this->newName = $this->realName . "-" . time() . "." . $this->extension;
}

public function upload()
{

    $destination = CONFIG["upload_dir"] . "/" . $this->newName;
    move_uploaded_file($this->tmpName, $destination);
}
```

and controller

```
public function store(RequestInterface $request)
{
    // unqiue name created in construct circle   
    $file = new FileUploader($request->getFile("image"));
    // then upload the file
    $file->upload();
...
```

and upload dir (in config file)

```
'upload_dir' => PUBLIC_PATH."/uploads"
```

and constants

```
define("PUBLIC_PATH",BASE_PATH."/public");
define ('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

var_dump(CONFIG["upload_dir"]);

```
/var/www/cms/public/uploads
```

So.. any advice ?

Comment: Where do you set `$this->newName;` to some usable value?

Comment: Is the server running SELinux? That can cause permission issues as well.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited my question

Comment: So where do you CALL `createUniqueName()`

Comment: a @BA_Webimax I didin't install selinux yet and as I know it's not default package for ubuntu

Comment: @RiggsFolly checkErrors -> checkExtension -> checkSize -> createUniqueName

Comment: can you show how the `createUniqueName()` and `upload()` are called?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited my question and added controller codes. createUniqueName() method calling inside of construct circle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but when I give 755 permission on app directory it start working.

it's interesting, I gave 755 permission `uploads`folder but it didn't work.